# Making a direcly link on the page

Tags: html

I want to do this:

this is the list
 - Option 1 how to keep warm
 - Option 2 how to keep cold

way down on the doc. comes the answer

here is the answer for keeping you warm  (this is were I want to go to. option 1)

Comment: You are looking for anchors. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for named anchor/named target/bookmark anchor links. Their format is essentially the same as that of normal anchors, however instead of pointing to a page, you point to the ID of the element you want to jump to.

For example:

```
<a href="#option1">Option 1 how to keep warm</a>
```

Then further on down the page:

```
<h4 id="option1">here is the answer for keeping you warm</h4>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a, specifically the section that says:

> **href** This is the single required attribute for anchors defining a hypertext source link. It indicates the link target, either a URL or a
>   URL fragment. **A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#),
>   which specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current
>   document**. URLs are not restricted to Web (HTTP)-based documents. URLs
>   might use any protocol supported by the browser. For example, file,
>   ftp, and mailto work in most user agents.